# Is it necessary to use 'sudo' when doing a '--dry-run' with apt-get?

Tags: apt, sudo, testing

I am doing tests on packages with the `apt-get --dry-run` command, however I am not using `sudo`. Could not using `sudo` affect the results in some way, or is `sudo` not necessary for such a simulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `apt-get --dry-run` without `sudo`, you get a warning:

```
  NOTE: This is only a simulation!
  apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
  Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
  so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
```

So it is better to use `sudo` to get a real testing.